# Angular inputfield under another inputfield

Tags: html, angular, for-loop

I want to create `inputfield` for every question that is on the site, but the `inputfields` are beside each other. I want to create `inputfields` that is under another `inputfield`.

The HTML looks like this:

```
        <li *ngFor="let item of unteraufgaben; let i = index">
                <form [formGroup]='antwort'>
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput placeholder="Antwort" [type]="'text'" name="unterantwort"
                            [formControl]="antwort.get('antwort'+i)" autocomplete="off">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </form>
    </li>
```

And Picture of the Website is as follow:
[image: Picture of the Website]

Comment: You should put the *ngFor="let item of unteraufgaben; let i = index"  in <ul> e.g. <ul *ngFor="let item of unteraufgaben; let i = index">...</ul> element and then you will get each <mat-form-field> in each <li>. pass <ul> then just a bootstrap class to prevent adding the styles (dots or other signs) for li. But you must then place <form [formGroup]='antwort'> over the main <ul> element in the top of oyur HTML page based on your concept.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Can i add it as an answer fi did solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    <form [formGroup]="antwort">
        <ul *ngFor="let item of unteraufgaben; let i = index">
           <li class="list-unstyled clearfix">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="Antwort" [type]="'text'" name="unterantwort" [formControl]="antwort.get('antwort'+i)" autocomplete="off">
                </mat-form-field>
          </li>
        </ul>
   </form>
```

or just this option if you don't really need unordered list:

```
 <form [formGroup]="antwort">
    <div *ngFor="let item of unteraufgaben; let i = index">
         <mat-form-field class="clearfix">
                <input matInput placeholder="Antwort" [type]="'text'" name="unterantwort" [formControl]="antwort.get('antwort'+i)" autocomplete="off">
         </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<br>` after the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `mat-form-field` inside a `div` and give that `div` styling->
display- flex, flex-direction- column

Comment: <div style="display-flex, flex-direction-column"> like this?

Comment: i tried this <div style="flex-direction:column"> but still no change